# flex box with ox component in MUI doesn't work with Toolbar

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

when I try tp align item in toolbar with flex box it doesn't work

```
<AppBar
        sx={{
          width: { sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)` },
          ml: { sm: `${drawerWidth}px` },
        }}
        position="fixed"
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <Box>
              <IconButton>
                <MenuIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
            <Box>
              <IconButton>
                <MailIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton>
                <InboxIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
```

and it works only when I remove Toolbar tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only quickly tested the code but I think this is because `Box` wrapped in `Toolbar` is not taking full width of its container, and should be solved removing the extra `Box`, and adding the layout styles on `Toolbar` instead.

Tested the code here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-slxjoc?file=src/App.js)

```
<AppBar
  sx={{
    width: { sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)` },
    ml: { sm: `${drawerWidth}px` },
  }}
  position="fixed"
>
  <Toolbar sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
    <Box>
      <IconButton>
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Box>
    <Box>
      <IconButton>
        <MailIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton>
        <InboxIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Box>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```